# retrieve data from wordpress and load into app in phonegap

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, cordova

i have been working in my first app but i can't load content from my blog, i visted a los of tutorials and implement codes from others but nothing.
is there anybody can give my a hand?

this is part of the code:

javascript:

```
<script>
        $( document).ready(function (){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://ultravoz.org/api/get_recent_posts/",
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(){
                    alert( 'Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed' );
                },
                success: function(data ){             
                    var html = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">' ;
                    for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {

                        html += '<li>';

                        html += '<div class="entry">' + the_title() + '</div>' ;

                        html += '</li>';
                    }
                    html += '</ul>';
                    $( "#postlist" ).append(html);
                    $( "#postlist ul[data-role=listview]" ).listview();

                }});
            }); 
    </script>
```

and the html:

```
<div id="blog" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" class="sys_hd" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_header" >
            <h1>Sysads Posts</h1>
        </div><!-- header -->
        <div data-theme="c" data-role="content" id="postlist"> 
        </div><!-- content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_footer" >
                    <div data-role="navbar" >
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Disclaimer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- navbar --> 
        </div><!-- footer --> 
    </div><!-- page -->
```

please, i have been spending a lot of time searching for a solution but nothing, and in know that i'm not good at programming but i'm working very hard to give the best i can.

regards

Comment: do you have try this code without embded in cordova ? what is your error ? which version of Phonegap do you use ?

Comment: i didn't try in cordova, just i'm looking for a simple example to load content from wordpress to start developing my app. this is the error:   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ultravoz.org/api/get_recent_posts/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: the latest version of phonegap i have recently installed.

Comment: oh I see, this error is a security question, for cross domain like in iframe tag, this could help you to understand your problem http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43639/why-is-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-necessary

Comment: is posible someone can post a simple example to load some data from worpress, and how to solve the security problem? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add:

```
    <access origin="*" />
```

to your config.xml file for phonegap to be able to complete this request.

To get this working in web I did this:

```
<script>
    $( document).ready(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://ultravoz.org/api/get_recent_posts/",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            error: function(){
                alert( 'Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed' );
            },
            success: function(data ){
                var html = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">' ;
                for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {

                    html += '<li>';

                    html += '<div class="entry">' + data.posts[i].title+ '</div>' ;

                    html += '</li>';
                }
                html += '</ul>';
                $( "#postlist" ).append(html);
                $( "#postlist ul[data-role=listview]" ).listview();

            }});
    });
</script>
```

You need to use 'jsonp' for crossdomain requests. I also updated where you have "the_title()", that is a wordpress function and will only work on an actual wordpress page.